# Where "Application Autostart" of Lubuntu 20.04 keeps its data?

Tags: lubuntu, configuration, autostart

Where "Application Autostart" of Lubuntu 20.04 keeps its data?

I want to backup its config file.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick way to see the list of directories is via *About LXQt*

[image]

You'll see it lists a number of Xdg Autostart Directories, plus the user's directory I mentioned earlier in comments for items added by users (ie. `~/.config/autostart/`)